# Resources for learning Spectral theory?

Tags: reference-request, spectral-theory

I am an independent researcher focusing on the application of dynamical systems theory mainly focusing on complex dynamics and Ergodic theory. I am looking for resources to learn more about spectral theory.

I have a decent foundation in math but it’s not perfect but I have been managing.

Comment: What kind of spectral theory are you interested in? It is quite a wide field. You might also want to check out this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187134/what-is-the-best-reference-for-spectral-theory

Comment: I am working with quantum mechanical and relativistic modeling currently. Although my main areas of interest for this angle are complex dynamics and Ergodic theory as of now. Perhaps Spectral Graph theory material could be quite useful as well?

Comment: If you care about quantum mechanics, I'd suggest that you have a look at Reed-Simon.

Comment: Do you also have general text recommendations with a pure mathematical approach? I generally learn best from books that kinda have an in between or motivated angle using pure mathematics.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know such a ressources. However, I would strongly suggest you give Reed/Simon a try. It is a fantastic source for spectral theory and it also develops all the functional analysis needed.